# Spring Active Directory Authentication using "proxy" user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-ldap

I have special requirement in my project that states that authentication against Active Directory should be done using a special ("proxy") user. That is, first we must log in to the AD using this special user, and then we should "query" the AD about if the credentials of the "real" user (the one who is trying to log in to my application) are correct, using the "proxy" user session.

Is there a way to do this using spring security? ... Right now I'm using `org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`.

These are my current dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is the configuration of the authentication part via spring:

```
<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:value>${security.ad.domain}</beans:value>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:value>${security.ad.url}</beans:value>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried successfully your scenario. Maybe late but it might help others.
Firstly, I set up my project as described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/).
Secondly, I added the following to my `WebSecurityConfig` class:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            // User Base DN
            .userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=...,ou=...,o=...,c=...") 
            .contextSource()
                // ldap server
                .url("ldaps://server:636") 
                // Bind credentials Bind DN
                .managerDn("cn=...,ou=...,o=...,c=...") 
                // Bind credentials Bind Password
                .managerPassword("...");
}
```